# How do I fix ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I am currently learning how sentiment analysis and machine learning works. I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/twitter-sentiment-analysis-with-deep-learning-using-bert-and-hugging-face-830005bcdbbf) and this is the [Github](https://github.com/baotramduong/Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-with-Deep-Learning-using-BERT/blob/main/Notebook.ipynb) source code. When it comes to training the model, I am facing this error:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets
```

Upon researching solutions on the internet, I found that it could be due to the presence of continuous values. I have tried to change this line but to no avail:
`val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, true_vals)`
to
`val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, np.round(true_vals))`

Here is the relevant part of the codes:

```
def evaluate(dataloader_val):

    #evaluation mode disables the dropout layer 
    model.eval()
    
    #tracking variables
    loss_val_total = 0
    predictions, true_vals = [], []
    
    for batch in tqdm(dataloader_val):
        
        #load into GPU
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
        
        #define inputs
        inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels':         batch[2]}

        #compute logits
        with torch.no_grad():        
            outputs = model(**inputs)
        
        #compute loss
        loss = outputs[0]
        logits = outputs[1]
        loss_val_total += loss.item()

        #compute accuracy
        logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = inputs['labels'].cpu().numpy()
        predictions.append(logits)
        true_vals.append(label_ids)
    
    #compute average loss
    loss_val_avg = loss_val_total/len(dataloader_val) 
    
    predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
    true_vals = np.concatenate(true_vals, axis=0)
            
    return loss_val_avg, predictions, true_vals


for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):

    #set model in train mode
    model.train()

    #tracking variable
    loss_train_total = 0
    
    #set up progress bar
    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, 
                        desc='Epoch {:1d}'.format(epoch), 
                        leave=False, 
                        disable=False)
    
    for batch in progress_bar:
        #set gradient to 0
        model.zero_grad()

        #load into GPU
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)

        #define inputs
        inputs = {'input_ids': batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels': batch[2]}
        
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        loss = outputs[0] #output.loss
        loss_train_total +=loss.item()

        #backward pass to get gradients
        loss.backward()
        
        #clip the norm of the gradients to 1.0 to prevent exploding gradients
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
        
        #update optimizer
        optimizer.step()

        #update scheduler
        scheduler.step()
        
        progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()/len(batch))})     
    
    tqdm.write('\nEpoch {epoch}')
    
    #print training result
    loss_train_avg = loss_train_total/len(dataloader_train)
    tqdm.write(f'Training loss: {loss_train_avg}')
    
    #evaluate
    val_loss, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(dataloader_val)
    
    #f1 score
    #val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, true_vals) #old
    val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, np.round(true_vals)) #new
    tqdm.write(f'Validation loss: {val_loss}')
    tqdm.write(f'F1 Score (weighted): {val_f1}')
```

I am new to this and I really wanna know the actual reasoning and working solution behind the error I am facing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add the header of each arrays `predictions` and `true_vals` along with their type!

Comment: hi @meti i have updated the question accordingly